# Mod rewrite apache recursive URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

My site is getting the following requests:

services/AA/BB/CC/DD

I am trying to get the following result:

services/AACC  resource1=BB resource2=DD

for that case, i am using the rule-

RewriteRule services/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/(.[^/]*)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/(.[^/]*)$ /services/$1$3?resource1=$2&resource3=$4    [QSA,L]

The problem is that I can get N resources. 
services/AA/BB/CC/DD/EE/FF
services/AACCEE  resource1=BB resource2=DD resource3=EE

services/AA/BB/CC/DD/EE/FF/GG/HH
services/AACCEEGG  resource1=BB resource2=DD resource3=EE resource4=GG

How can I write this rule to be more generic ?